# Simple Transformers producing nothing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, seq2seq, simpletransformers

I have a simple transformers script looking like this.

```
from simpletransformers.seq2seq import Seq2SeqModel, Seq2SeqArgs
args = Seq2SeqArgs()
args.num_train_epoch=5
model = Seq2SeqModel(
    "roberta",
    "roberta-base",
    "bert-base-cased",
)
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('english-french.csv')
df['input_text'] = df['english'].values
df['target_text'] =df['french'].values
model.train_model(df.head(1000))
print(model.eval_model(df.tail(10)))
```

The eval_loss is `{'eval_loss': 0.0001931049264385365}`

However when I run my prediction script

```
to_predict = ["They went to the public swimming pool."]
predictions=model.predict(to_predict)
```

I get this

```
['']
```

The dataset I used is [here](https://www.kaggle.com/faouzimohamed/englishfrench-fornmt?select=english-french.csv)

I'm very confused on the output. Any help or explanation why it returns nothing would be much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you should check the dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this model instead.

```
model = Seq2SeqModel(
    encoder_decoder_type="marian",
    encoder_decoder_name="Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-en-mul",
    args=args,
    use_cuda=True,
)
```

roBERTa is not a good option for your task.

I have rewritten your code on [this colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Ft6P-c-uQWzx5zYn1hikXRjvwGwRSIxI?usp=sharing)

**Results**

```
# Input
to_predict = ["They went to the public swimming pool.", "she was driving the shiny black car."]
predictions = model.predict(to_predict)
print(predictions)

# Output
['Ils aient cher à la piscine publice.', 'elle conduit la véricine noir glancer.']
```

Comment: I have trained the model for just one epoch and 1000 samples. You can change the data and epochs etc. whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks!!! However is it possible to train MarianMT for custom languages such as let's say scifi one.

Comment: You can search from a list. There are thousands of models available on https://huggingface.co/models?search=helsinki-nlp

Comment: No issue boss..